# Missing pom errror in maven while downloading ws4j dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, ws4j

I want to use ws4j for my project. And i can't able to connect to the internet all the time. So, most of time i download dependency to local repository using **dependency:get** command. Then i use it in project.
like that i tried download **ws4j-1.0.1**. But i get a error while downloading. It says `Missing POM for edu.cmu.lti:ws4j:jar:1.0.1`. But there is a pom file in the repository. see the url [ws4j repository](https://dl.bintray.com/kemlg/wordnet-utils/edu/cmu/lti/ws4j/1.0.1/). But why i get the error.

The command i used was `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=edu.cmu.lti:ws4j:1.0.1`

The image of the error i get

[image: image of error]

I am using maven **version 3.6.3**

Please, someone help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=edu.cmu.lti:ws4j:1.0.1**

This tries to download the dependency from **https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/** and since it does not find the dependency there, it fails.
You need to specify "**-DremoteRepositories**" to fetch it from a remote repository.

For example: mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.apache.maven:maven-core:2.2.1:jar:sources **-DremoteRepositories=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2** -Ddest=/tmp/myfile.jar

Please refer https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html